# Rails 3.2 undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nomethoderror

For some reason I started to get this error after switching to Rails 3.2. I guess it has something to do with acl9 plugin, which I tried reinstalling, but nothing changed.

I moved the plugins to lib/plugins and added initializer to config/initializers but again, same error.

I looked for solution at acl9 repo on Github, but could not find anything there. Maybe it is not acl9 after all.

I have paperclip, acl9, authlogic installed.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass):
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3140920687338355213__call__3168118505970967148__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/project/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/project/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/project/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

EDIT (SOLVED): It took quite a while to figure out and I am still not quite sure what happened. I think it has to do with acl9's support for Rails 3.1+ But in the end I took the acl9 code from github and everything suddenly started working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am a newbie to RoR and got the same error while going through RoR "Getting started guide".

This may sound silly, but others might make the same mistake as I am, so posting what I noticed in RoR from newbie's eyes,

```
validates :name,  : presence => true
```

Note ": presence", it should be ":presence". Now the Rail throws a Syntax error

```
 C:/blog/app/models/post.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
 validates :name,  : presence => true
```

But if you "Refresh" Your browser, it hides the syntax error, instead gives

```
undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems Rails caching is the culprit. :)

Comment: yeah that is actually usually the case.. that's how I came across this problem at least. I will accept the answer until someone can provide a deeper insight..

Comment: I do Rails professionally, and valdiates still is not the same thing as validates.

Comment: for future reference - had the same problem because of a typo: i wrote validate instead of validates

Answer (score 9):

This may not be your issue as it sounds like you already had working code to begin with, but for future reference for others, I ran into the same error due to a simple typo inside my model code, like so:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :content, :length => { maximum => 10 }
end
```

which should have been:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :content, :length => { :maximum => 10 }
end
```

Note the "maximum" vs. ":maximum" -- this resulted in the exact nil error above, and went away when I fixed that typo.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is the same bug, but I was having a similar issue. On a first load of a buggy model, **Rails** responds with a **Routing error** and then for the requests coming afterwards it responds with `undefined method 'key?' for nil:NilClass` and same stack trace.

This looks to be a bug with **Rails class caching**, but can get around by enabling class caching or disabling on change class reloading.

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

or

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```

Answer (score 6):

I agree with bmoeskau that you should check your model code for bugs. To my surprise, models apparently sometimes get loaded during the *routing* phase. I discovered:

1. The code that causes the problem, in my case, is in the model, not in the controller where I would expect it.
2. The `` undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass `` error often only occurs after the first time I access the page.

As far as I can tell, what happens is

1. Suppose we have a scaffold for Examples, with some bad code in `app/models/example.rb`
2. A request is made for `/examples`
3. The routing part of Rails matches that to `app/controllers/examples_controller.rb` but it *first* loads `app/models/example.rb`. I don't know why it loads the model, but the effect is, I conjecture: The error in the model stops short a part of the routing code, corrupting its construction of a cache of routes.
4. At this point, if I'm lucky the error will be reported back to me in the browser. Sometimes, however, I simply get a message saying `No route matches [GET] "/examples"` (To be fair to Rails, this added complication seems to be the fault of not using `resources :examples` to make the route. The following happens regardless).
5. A second request is made for `/examples`
6. Conjecture: This time the Rails routing code tries to use its cached reference to `app/controllers/examples_controller.rb` but the routes cache is corrupt (a variable is `nil`) because the code that sets never finished running.

This last item is most annoying because the problem that caused it (the bad code in the model) isn't even being run.