# undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, railscasts

I'm new to Rails and was following Ryan Bate's tutorial on how to make a simple authentication system (http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?autoplay=true) and I was just going through it but got this error: `

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#new

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Sites/authentication`
```

I don't really know what this means since I'm just a beginner, but these are my files:

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
    <%= form for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div class="error_messages">
    <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
    <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>
<p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
    Authentication::Application.routes.draw do
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  root :to => "users#new"
  resources :users
 end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    before_save :encrypt_password

    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => create
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secrete(password, password_salt)
    end
end
```

I think the tutorial was made for Rails 3.1 or some version of rails 3. But I am using Rails 3.2, that might be part of the problem. But since I'm a beginner I have no idea what is going on. Could someone tell me what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the offending line:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => create
```

Change it to

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
```

Also, ***do*** look at [suggestions that stackoverflow shows you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440325/rails-3-2-undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass) when you write a question. Reading those suggestions prevents 95% of my questions.

#### Update

There's another line

```
<%= form for @user do |f| %>
```

Should be

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

Now please go and triple check that you typed all the code as you should :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still get the same error. And thank you for the Stack Overflow tip, I'm new to stack overflow as well.

Comment: also, if you've stumbled onto the Q&A, you also need to add `gem 'bcrypt-ruby'` to your `Gemfile` which is at the top level directory of your rails project. once you add that, restart.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem, and a simple restart of my server solved it.

Comment: It works! I just don' know that restart is needed in Rails sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in User model has a typo on secret.

```
self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secrete(password, password_salt)
```

It should be

```
self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secrete(password, password_salt)
end
```

You also forgot to add the end for the if statement. It should be

```
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secrete(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with installing bcrypt-ruby of 3.0.x version against default. Specify it on Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```