# Error Simple Login "undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Please help-me i wen make a simple login and this error appear when i test this.
Please how i solve this error?

NoMethodError in UserController#login

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

```
  def login
    if request.post?
      if session[:user] = User.authenticate(params[:user][:login],params[:user][:password])
        flash[:message] = 'Voce esta Logado !'
        redirect_to_stored
      else
        flash[:warning] = 'Usuario e/ou Senha incorreta !'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952568/undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass)

Answer (score 0):

This type of question has already been answered. You should find the solution to your answer here. Make sure, that you read all the steps and check your User model for the required validation that is causing the problem.

[undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952568/undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass)