# acl9 doesn't fill created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, acl9

I followed the acl9 Readme exactly, have double checked everything and still get the following error when trying to use `has_role!(:admin)`.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: roles_users.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("user_id", "role_id") VALUES (1, 1)
```

The only catch is that I am using Rails 3.2 and used the following fix for an error: [Rails 3.2 undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440325/rails-3-2-undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in rails. Hopefully it will be resolved and reported on [here](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations/issues/47).

I fixed it by eliminated the `has_and_belongs_to_many` lines from the corresponding model class, and for some reason that made it go away.

Comment: Haha, well at least I know I'm not alone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was also caused by an error in the acl9 docs (because a habtm join table shouldn't have timestamps). I fixed [the docs](https://github.com/be9/acl9/wiki/Role-Subsystem#subject-model) too, and acl9 1.2 now has a generator for that migration too :)