# I get "undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass" for all errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, error-handling

My Rails version is 3.0.4.rc1 and ruby 1.9.3p194

I am facing very weird problem.

In my project I am getting `ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method`has_key?' for nil:NilClass`in development.log file and`Internal Server Error undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass` in browser.

For any error, if its invalid statement, undefined variable, raise, exit, wrong database name.. or anything else, I get the above error message only. It is so frustrating, I cant get to know what is the error or where(line number and file name) is the error.

It works fine if there is no error, but when there is any error(raise, exit, or any other errors) it shows the same error message. i.e. `undefined method`has_key?' for nil:NilClass`

Error log:

```
[2013-04-19 14:41:07] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.4.rc1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:20:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.4.rc1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.4.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.4.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.4.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.4.rc1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/home/shweta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/shweta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/shweta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/shweta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

[this states that such issue arises when there is a syntax error in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440325/rails-3-2-undefined-method-key-for-nilnilclass#answer-12668009), but my model files are fine.

Please help.

P.s. I don't have this issue in rails console.

Comment: provide us some code. Find for method has_key? and see to which object its applied

Comment: As the problem does not seem to appear in console, I guess it is located either in your environment config, either in your logger config (if the logger fails, it still results in an internal server error). Did you mess with `config.whiny_nils`, or did you tweak the logger ?

Comment: @m_x, I have `config.whiny_nils = true` in config/environments/development.rb file

Comment: did you try to shut it off ? whiny_nils has been removed from AS shortly after rails 3. Maybe a more recent gem in your project may interact weirdly with this.

Comment: @m_x, I set `config.whiny_nils` to `false` or comment it out, issue remains the same(after each change I restarted the server).

Comment: sorry, I have no clue :(

Comment: Since the error is only occurring through the browser, are you intercepting ("rescuing") in your ApplicationController? Also, make sure you have done a `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: @scarver2, It works fine if there is no error, but when there is any error(raise, exit, or any other errors) it shows the same error message. i.e. undefined methodhas_key?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Why are you running a release candidate of Rails? Also, Ruby 1.9.3p194 has known issues. I recommend upgrading to at least Rails 3.1 and 1.9.3p327. This is a painless procedure using Git and RVM.

Comment: I have other projects running fine in ruby 1.9.3p194 but their rails version is not 3.0.4.rc1, I think this issue is due to the rails version that I am using.